# Change Grails <g:findAll> expr with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, grails

I have the following code in my gsp, where I want to retrieve the client -> with id == x from clientList. What I wanted to happen is, when the user selects on the client from the list, it should load the details of the client with a modal popup hence I need the client object to derive the information from.

```
<g:findAll id="show-client" in="${clientList}" expr="it.id == x">
```

I've tried placing

```
$('#show-client').attr('expr', 'it.id == ${client.id}');
```

on my onclick function, but to no avail does it change the expr of g:findAll.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<g:findAll>` tag is evaluated server-side and it generates HTML dynamically.  There is no way to interact with this tag with javascript, unless you look at the generated HTML and interact with that (using javascript).

In order to accomplish this, you'll probably have to add an ajax call triggered when a user selects a client in order to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: can you please provide an example on how I can go about doing that? thank you so much.

Comment: I can't provide an example without knowing what the HTML is that gets generated.  The best way to get this is to open the page with the <g:findAll> element in a browser and view source on the page and then copy the generated HTML into your question.  :)  Thanks in advance!